# Equivalent Java code of Sahi script: _openWindow("http://www.google.com","defaultSahiPopup",[360,640]);

Tags: java, sahi

I have modified "controller.mode=sahi" at sahi.properties file as "controller.mode=java" for recording Java code in Sahi Web Test Automation Tool. I want to record my tests using with Resolution of browser (for example, 360x640). During recording the tests with resolution of 360x640, I did the following:

1. I filled up "Enter start URL" text field  as http://www.google.com
2. I checked "Use with Resolution" check box and enter 360x640
3. Click Go button

After recording I found the following code on Sahi Controller:

```
_openWindow("http://www.google.com","defaultSahiPopup",[360,640]); _selectWindow("defaultSahiPopup");
```

But unfortunately, the above code is not Java code. It is Sahi script I think. I need Java code in Sahi for opening the browser with the specific Resolution. What's the java code for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of Srini from Tyto Software (http://sahi.co.in/), I have got the solution. Equivalent java code for the above sahi script is as below:

```
browser.execute("_sahi._openWindow('http://www.google.com','defaultSahiPopup',[360,640]);");
browser.execute("_sahi._selectWindow('defaultSahiPopup');");
```